# How do i execute this cron job from a mac?

Tags: bash, macos, cron

I have a bash script that I can execute with `cd ~/Documents/Code/shhh/ && ./testy` if i'm in any directory on my computer and that successfully pushes to github which is what i want.

I'm trying to schedule a cron job to do this daily so I ran `crontab -e` which opens a nano editor and then I put `30 20 * * * cd ~/Documents/Code/shhh/ && ./testy` to run daily at 10:30pm and hit control O, enter and control X. But still it it didn't execute.  When I type `crontab -l` it shows my command & I have a `You have new mail.` message when I open a new window.  Still my command doesn't execute even though it will when I run it from any other directory.

I think my crontab job is at `/var/at/tmp` so I ran `30 20 * * * cd ../../../Users/squirrel/Documents/Code/shhh/ && ./testy` but still nothing, even though it does work when I write it out myself from that directory.  Sidenote, I can't enter into the tmp folder even after using sudo

OK When I type in `mail` I see a lot message and inside i get this error

`---------------Checking Status of 2---------------
[master 0c1fff8] hardyharhar
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured`

Comment: Why do you think keeping the editor open would help? Did you save the file?

Comment: @tripleee Haha not sure.  I don't know nano that well.  I ran control O.  Doesn't that save it?

Comment: Maybe see https://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/mac-osx-startup-crontab-launchd-jobs

Comment: I dunno, I don't use `nano`. Quick googling suggests yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you by default open `nano Input_file` it opens it up in INSERT mode(unlike `vi` where we have to explicitly go to INSERT mode by pressing `i` key). Now when you have done `CTNRL+O` it will then ask you if you want to save changes to opened file or not eg--> `File Name to Write: Input_file` If you press ENTER then it will save it and will be back on the screen(to your Input_file) where you entered new line. Now you could press `CONTRL+X` to come out of Input_file. May be you are stuck after saving it and want to come out then try this out once?

Comment: Ok I tried pressing enter and i got this 
```crontab: installing new crontab```
```$ crontab -l```
```5 23 * * * cd ~/Documents/Code/shhh/ && ./testy```

Comment: That looks promising, but it's still not running

Comment: @Squirrl, after pressing `cntrl+O` you will be asked to save it, then hit enter it will save entry. Now come out of it by doing `CNTRL+X` where are you stuck please let us know?

Comment: I'm not stuck on that.  I got that part now thank you very much.  Now it's just not executing.  If i run `cd ~/Documents/Code/shhh/ && ./testy` from anywhere else it runs my script, but when i put `5 23 * * * cd ~/Documents/Code/shhh/ && ./testy` in the `/tmp/crontab.L8REs9jMFP ` file is not running

Comment: It says `You have new mail.` now when i open a new window, and `crontab -l` shows something as well

Comment: Could you please try to give complete path instead of tilde sign, just make sure path exists what you are mentioning.

Comment: I tried this as well `../../../Users/squirrel/Documents/Code/shhh/ && ./testy` see above edit

Comment: @Squirrl, no this is a relative path so you should give path eg--> `/root/test/singh/your_script/` etc.

Answer (score 1):

`crontab -e` does not edit the crontab file "live" at all -- changes are saved to the active file only after you save changes *and* exit the editor.

It also sounds like you may be using incorrect directory paths. The command in a crontab entry will generally be executed starting from the user's home directory. So if your home directory is /Users/squirrl, the command `cd ../parent_directory/` will try to move to /Users/parent_directory. I suspect this is not what you want.

Finally, note that cron jobs run with a very minimal environment, without running most of your usual shell setup files (e.g. .bashrc). Most notably, if your script uses any commands that aren't in /bin or /usr/bin, you'll either need to use explicit full paths to them, or change the PATH variable to include the directories they're in.

Comment: I edited the question above.  I'm now running `30 20 * * * cd ~/Documents/Code/shhh/ && ./testy` The command `cd ~/Documents/Code/shhh/ && ./testy` works from any directory from my computer but not with the cron job. Thanks!

Comment: There's probably something in the script that depends on your normal setup (e.g. the `PATH` problem I mentioned). I'd recommend capturing its output by adding something like `>/tmp/test.log 2>&1` to the command in the crontab. [This question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it) has some additional suggestions for troubleshooting.